# Jira Api: Why is description being merged with summary, when creating a new issue?

Tags: json, powershell, jira, jira-rest-api

I'm creating a Powershell script for monitoring disk space and creating issues on Jira, with how much disk space is left.

I can't seem to figure out how to separate my summary and my description. They are "merged" together, and are both being passed into the summary when the issue is created.

[image: The created Jira issue]

I'm guessing that the formatting of my JSON body might just be off, but I can't seem to figure out what I've done wrong.

The body i'm sending is looking like this:

```
$body = 
'{
    "fields":
    {
        "project":
        {
           "key": "' + $projectKey + '"
        },
        "issuetype":
        {
            "name": "' + $issueType + '"
        },
        "summary": "' + $summary + '",
        "description": "' + $description + '",
        "priority":
        {
            "id": "' + $priority + '"
        }
    }
}';
```

summary and description looks like this:

```
$description = "{0}% space is available on the {1} drive. {2} of {3} GB of space is available." -f [math]::truncate($diskSpace), $drive, [math]::truncate($currentDrive.FreeSpace / 1gb), [math]::truncate($currentDrive.Size / 1gb);
$summary = "There is plenty of space left on the {0} drive" -f , $drive;
```

Comment: What might help you is creating an object and then using `ConvertTo-Json`, e.g. `@{a=1;b=2;} | ConvertTo-Json`, there is much less room for error versus trying to manually create the object via string interpolation.

Comment: Awesome, I'll look into using that. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue wasn't the JSON, but the way I called my function, which was responsible for creating the Jira.

I changed it from this:

```
CreateJira($summary, $description)
```

To This:

```
CreateJira $summary, $description
```